# Guzzle POST request: required body when execute request

Tags: laravel, guzzle

I have a POST request with Guzzle like this:

```
// Return a collection
$cart = $this->getCart('2019-10-08 07:08:39');

//Return first entry of the collection with first()
$template = $this->getTemplate($config->key);

        $isDetail = null;

        foreach ($cart as $item) {
            try {
                $client = $this->getClient();

                $headers = ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'];

                $body = [
                    'user_id'   => $item->mystore_user_id,
                    'title'     => $template->title,
                    'message'   => $template->message,
                    'avatar'    => $template->avatar,
                    'detail_id' => $isDetail,
                    'schedule'  => null
                ];

                print_r($body);

                $response = $client->post('push-noti/unicast', $headers, $body);

                print_r(response()->json(json_decode($response->getBody(), true)));

            } catch (QueryException | \Exception $ex) {
                echo "Error!";
            }
        }
```

My body variable value is exist in each loop when it printed. But when I use it in $client->post, my request return error with user_id, title, message is required. I really don't know why is it?

Can you tell me what's wrong in my code?

Thank you!

Comment: Try to replace `$body` by `[ 'form_params' => $body]` !

Comment: it's still got that error, 3 first fields is required. So weird!

Comment: you call your webservice or a third part WS ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 $response = $client->post('push-noti/unicast', ['body' => $body , 'headers' => $headers]);
```

If you are calling a third party API, replace `push-noti/unicast` with complete URL.